# add 'tools:replace="Android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest, android-support-library

I'm following a tutorial in HeadFirst Android development and encountered issues after adding:
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

The control was deprecated so I followed instructions on Stack to resolve that issue by adding com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1 to the app modules Dependencies

But now I'm getting the following build errors:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.

Here is the code:

Comment: I added the following to my Manifest:             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<meta-data>
            tools:replace="android:value"</meta-data> then got the following error:  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: add version 25.3.1 for every supportlibrary like : recyclerview-v7 ,support-v4 , design: in build.gradle as :-                                                       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

Answer (score 186):

Problem is that all support libraries with same version and major version has to match compile SDK version.

So try to force a specific support library version.
Put this at the end of your app module in `build.gradle`.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure why it is not accepted as valid answer.

Comment: Whats major version and same version mean? +1 for working solution.

Comment: @sagar giri I get can't resolve symbol 'DependencyResolveDetails' error for this. can you tell me the solution

Comment: @D.hodges this is the working solution. kindly accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Should be accepted as valid answer

Comment: this works for me as well. @sagar giri  can u plz explain what this method is doing, how it is working. plz i want to know this code expalination.

Comment: thnx @sagar giri

Comment: If I build with a Jenkins Pipeline, i don't have access to build.gradle, because build it in realtime execution. How I solve it?

Comment: work for me! 2018-April. my project was React Native 0.51. after Android Studio update it got all kind of small problem. and I use this one, it work! (and then I upgrade from React Native 0.51 to 0.55

Answer (score 38):

First add this line to your manifest tag if you do not have yet:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.winanainc"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Then Add this meta tag inside your application to overwrite you build tools version, in this case for example I choosed the version 25.3.1

```
<application>
   ...
   ..
    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" />
</application>
```

Comment: Exactly whats needed

Answer (score 7):

```
        Add <meta-data> tag in manifest.xml file as below...


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest package="com.demo"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            **<meta-data
                tools:replace="android:value"
                android:name="android.support.VERSION"
                android:value="25.3.1" />//this 25.3.1 version should be same which we defined in the build.gradle file. i am using compileSdkVersion 25**

        </application>
 </manifest>
```

it will work @Ambilpura....

Answer (score 6):

```
 <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

            >
            <meta-data
                tools:replace="android:value"
                android:name="android.support.VERSION"
                android:value="26.0.0" />
        </application>
```

Answer (score 5):

Changed all support library versions to 25.3.1 and worked like a charm:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

You also need to change the following parameters to 25:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Answer (score 3):

Open **Android Studio -> Open Manifest File**

Add  `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback"/>`. Don't forget to include `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` too, before the `<application>` tag

replace

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

by

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

and add

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all solution but nothing work. After reading google docs I have found my solution that fixed my manifest merge issue.

Just add this simple line in manifest file:

```
<application
      ...
      tools:node="replace"
      ...
</application>
```

This fixed my issue.

If this doesn't work then try with these,

```
tools:node="merge-only-attributes"
tools:node="removeAll"
tools:node="replace"
```

You can find google docs from this link.
[Merge multiple manifest files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge)

Answer (score 1):

1. At Android Studio -> Open Manifest File
2. Switch to Merged Manifest and check Other Manifest file.

In my case I am using 26.1.0 support files but found support-v13 is 26.0.1
[image]

So I added `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'` to Gradle file and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

the answer by @sagar giri is a temporary work around. what i did to solve this is explained at the end.

If you have latest support library installed in latest android studio and if you have a old support library version in build gradle's app module, then android studio fails due to the version mismatch.

So update your support library version to latest one and fix latest support library changes like icon renaming etc and rebuild it.

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

This code resolved my problem

"Problem is that all support libraries with same version and major version has to match compile SDK version.

So try to force a specific support library version. Put this at the end of your app module in build.gradle."

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face this issue, the best approach is to run `Rebuild Project` - this will tell you exactly why this is happening.

In my case it was a `meta-data` present in both `module` and `app`

Answer (score -4):

add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.
add to Line AndroidManifest.xml:22