# When I Compile CardView with Gradle. There was an error. How to solve it?

Tags: android, compilation, cardview

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Comment: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml in <application tag

Answer (score 0):

please look at a similar post for solution

[Manifest merger failed Suggestion: add 'tools:replace=“Android:value”' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140059/manifest-merger-failed-suggestion-add-toolsreplace-androidvalue-to-meta)