# Cyborg dependency in Gradle isn't working

Tags: android, cyborg

I'm trying to add the Cyborg dependency and I'm getting an error in the Gradle when adding 
compile "com.nu-art-software.cyborg:cyborg-core:0.8.3" (as per the video)
Why doesn't that work?

edit: 
here's the error
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edvu8.png)

Comment: try to use `"com.nu-art-software.cyborg:cyborg-core:0.8.3@aar" `.

Comment: Alex, be more specific what is the error??

Comment: apologies... here's an image
https://snag.gy/OUklWD.jpg

Comment: I've added a Cyborg tag, please use it if you have any further questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I was not aware that it generates a meta value for the version... didn't experience this when I was recording the video.

[This should solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43272992/348189)