# Illegal Argument Exception | Issues with build-cache

Tags: android, android-studio, illegalargumentexception

I am getting

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 value=(26.0.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
>
> IllegalArgumentException: error getting error html: unexpected add suggestion format add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

I have tried all(`sync and build`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140059/manifest-merger-failed-suggestion-add-toolsreplace-androidvalue-to-meta), fixing version to 26.0.0, etc.) I could find on StackOverflow but in vain.

I think something is wrong in `Merged Mainfest` but don't exactly know what.

### Edit

Exception Raised(Illegal Argument Exception)

> error getting error html: unexpected add suggestion format add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected add suggestion format add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.getErrorAddHtml(ManifestPanel.java:614)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.getErrorHtml(ManifestPanel.java:580)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.updateDetails(ManifestPanel.java:475)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.valueChanged(ManifestPanel.java:370)
>       at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:635)
>       at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree$MySelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Tree.java:676)
>       at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1093)
>       at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:294)
>       at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:188)
>       at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1634)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2393)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3609)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3548)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.MouseEventAdapter.mousePressed(MouseEventAdapter.java:42)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:279)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6530)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.processMouseEvent(Tree.java:443)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected add suggestion format add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.getErrorAddHtml(ManifestPanel.java:614)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.getErrorHtml(ManifestPanel.java:580)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.updateDetails(ManifestPanel.java:475)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.valueChanged(ManifestPanel.java:373)
>       at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:635)
>       at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree$MySelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Tree.java:676)
>       at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.clearSelection(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:577)
>       at javax.swing.JTree.clearSelection(JTree.java:2667)
>       at javax.swing.JTree.setModel(JTree.java:851)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.setManifest(ManifestPanel.java:274)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestEditor.reload(ManifestEditor.java:110)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestEditor.selectNotify(ManifestEditor.java:175)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openFileImpl4$6(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:934)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2453)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:971)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl3(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:788)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openFileImpl2$4(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:770)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:122)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:100)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:86)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl2(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:770)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileWithProviders(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:711)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.ex.FileEditorManagerEx.openFile(FileEditorManagerEx.java:151)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openEditor$9(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1151)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:129)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:100)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:86)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openEditor(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1149)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.goToDeclaration(ManifestPanel.java:559)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel.access$100(ManifestPanel.java:105)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.editors.manifest.ManifestPanel$2.mouseClicked(ManifestPanel.java:226)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.processMouseEvent(Tree.java:443)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: [here](https://ideone.com/YppTSU)

Comment: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://s...content-available-to-author-only...d.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jason.notifier">`  What is this..?

Comment: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.jason.notifier">` update your manifest with this value.

Comment: it same as you said, while copying it printed that gibberish.

Comment: deleting build-cache`(it's in C:\Users\(Your Username)\.android\build cache)` folder solved the issue, don't know what was exactly happening.