# Google Play services Version Issue with adobe creative sdk library android

Tags: android, google-play-services, adobecreativesdk

I am using adobe creative sdk library in my photo editing application. When I add dependencies of this library in my application, it adds its necessary libraries in my project. It adds google play services base library version 9.4.0 which is not the latest version.So, problem is that when I add a google ads dependency in my project, it shows error as below:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.
```

So how can I update the play services base library version? it is not showing in my Gradle file but its showing in my external libraries of the project as shown below.

**Build.gradle dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
/* Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
//    compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
compile 'com.localytics.android:library:4.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
```

**External Libraries Directory**
[image]

Comment: use `gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath` for list all the version and identify the conflict

Comment: Why don't you use their latest sdk  `compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.2006-5'` Found it in their site https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/creativesdk/docs/androidsdk.html

Comment: I already found conflicts. conflict is between play services versions. adobe creative library ads playservices base version 9.4.0 and i am adding vesion 11.8.0 of google ads in my project.@OmInfowaveDevelopers

Comment: By changing version of adobe creative sdk to latest it's giving me this error. please help me what i have to do because i can't understand exactly what the error is saying and why it's come.@sunilsunny

Comment: Error:       Error:'Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
   is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.' @sunilsunny

Comment: Either you can you add 'tools:replace" as suggested or Just change compileSDk version, targetSDK version to 26 and support libraries to 26.0.1. or Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43272992/3111083

Comment: I have used the answer which you linked in your last comment. It solves my problem quitely. It solves conflict problem but it gives me error **transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug**. Can you please tell me meaning of this error and how can i solve it? @sunilsunny

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45835332/3111083