# Error -32601 received from application: Method not found , Flutter Upgrade issue in Android

Tags: android, flutter

After upgrading the flutter , when i build my app i started getting following error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. [   +5 ms] >
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   [  +23 ms]      is also present at
>   [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   value=(26.1.0). [   +8 ms]      Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

As explained in [add 'tools:replace="Android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140059/add-toolsreplace-androidvalue-to-meta-data-element-at-androidmanifest)  and 
 [Android: Getting "Manifest merger failed" error after updating to a new version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-updating-to-a-new-version/44931003) SO answers i added the

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.4.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to my app folder `build.gradle` :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.yourcompany.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.4.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now whenever i run my app i get the following Error :

> `Error -32601 received from application: Method not found`

I have tried by running `flutter clean`, the error still persists.

Here is output of `flutter doctor` :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0-rc1)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found out that the original issue :

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. [ +5 ms] >
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   [ +23 ms] is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0). [ +8 ms] Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Might have been due to older firebase packages dependencies.

My initial `pubspec.yaml` dependencies looked something like :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  contact_picker:  ^0.0.2
  connectivity: ^0.3.0
  image_picker: 0.1.1
  google_sign_in: 0.3.1
  firebase_analytics: 0.0.4
  firebase_auth: 0.2.0
  firebase_database: 0.0.1
  firebase_storage: 0.0.5
  firebase_messaging: 0.2.5
```

If i update the `pubspec.yaml` as  below :

> ```
>   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
>   contact_picker:  ^0.0.2
>   connectivity: ^0.3.0
>   image_picker: ^0.4.1
>   google_sign_in: ^3.0.3
>   firebase_analytics: ^0.3.3
>   firebase_auth: ^0.5.7
>   firebase_database: ^0.4.6
>   firebase_storage: ^0.3.3
>   firebase_messaging: ^0.2.5
> ```

There is no `Manifest merger failed` in first place hence no changes needed in build.gradle file.

I am not sure how the `Manifest merger failed` is linked to other firebase packages, however after this solution the build is working fine, and there are no `Manifest merger failed` or `Error -32601 received from application: Method not found` error.

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced that same error and can confirm that it was a Firestore package dependency error. I was attempting to update to `0.12.11` when I received the error `binding to the service failed`.

The solution was to go back to `0.12.10` Firestore plugin and that resolved the issue