# ionic3 error AndroidManifest.xml:53:66-112 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY> is provided?

Tags: ionic3, build.gradle, android-manifest

I got above error after build android in ionic3.

```
AndroidManifest.xml:53:66-112 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY> is provided
```

I tried each and everything but nothing is worked for me.i tried the below solution:

> 1st solution from this link
>
> [add 'tools:replace="Android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140059/add-toolsreplace-androidvalue-to-meta-data-element-at-androidmanifest) i have put below code in the build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2nd tried:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.winanainc"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Please tell me how to fix above error?

```js
//Project.properties file
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:27+
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/managment-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.+
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation/managment-dependencies.gradle
# cordova.system.library.14=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+
cordova.system.library.11=com.android.support:support-v4:26+
cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/managment-ignorelinterrors.gradle
# cordova.system.library.17=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+
cordova.system.library.13=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/managment-androidtarget.gradle
cordova.system.library.14=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.15=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
cordova.system.library.16=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+
cordova.system.library.17=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+
cordova.system.library.18=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+




//build.gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } // Fabrics Maven repository from cordova-plugin-firebase
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version-compatibilityon requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // fabric dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() // Google's Maven repository from cordova-plugin-firebase
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1.0'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "cordova-plugin-firebase/managment-build.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation/managment-dependencies.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/managment-ignorelinterrors.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/managment-androidtarget.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }
    
    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*

    ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

    else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }
    */

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: "CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (['validateReleaseSigning', 'validateSigningRelease', 'validateSigningArmv7Release', 'validateSigningX86Release'].contains(task.name)) {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

Comment: What is your cordova-plugin-googlemaps version?

Comment: Sir i am using 2.6.2 version of cordova-plugin-googlemaps sir i am not understand what the problem?

Comment: are you using onesignal by any chance? There is a related github issue https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2604 and https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/503

Comment: No sir i am not using any onesignal plugin i have used firebase for push notification?